# Does app bundle converts to apk during instalation on device from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to upload an app bundle to Google Play. And question is: **does .aab converts to .apk during instalation from GP like it is doing bundle tool for manual instalation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Google Play extracts apk from aab

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle